# How do you create a SQL Compact Edition Version 4.0 database with VS 2010 SP1?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'd like to build a class library that consumes a SQL Compact Database, but when I add one I always get a 3.5 version...how do I make a 4.0 version to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install the Visual Studio Tools for SQL Server Compact via WebPI (Web Platform installer)